# ORA-00976: LEVEL, PRIOR, or ROWNUM not allowed here

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using LEVEL in a left join. 
I got this error:

ORA-00976: LEVEL, PRIOR, or ROWNUM not allowed here

Everywhere I'm searching says remove level, but I can't remove level. Where is level allowed?

```
SELECT t1.report_id, coalesce(t1.field_desc, t2.field_desc, 'None') field_desc
FROM dual
LEFT JOIN v_my_view t1
ON t1.priority= 1
AND t1.field_id  NOT IN (
  (SELECT to_number( regexp_substr(
  (SELECT value FROM table WHERE KEY='property'
  ),'[^,]+',1,level ) )
FROM dual
  CONNECT BY to_number( regexp_substr(
  (SELECT value FROM table WHERE KEY='property'
  ),'[^,]+',1,level )) IS NOT NULL
) )
LEFT JOIN  v_my_view  t2
ON t1.report_id = t2.report_id
AND t1.priority= 2;
```

Comment: I believe `LEVEL` is defined only in conjunction with `CONNECT BY`.  Your sub-query does not have `CONNECT BY`.  See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm

Comment: Doesn't the Connect by on line 10 do that?

Comment: That subquery runs alone correctly. It looks like it doesn't work in a left join?